# "Unique:=True " syntax in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba excel and working with Advance filter in vba excel for some school assignment.

I came across the code "Unique:=True". I'm trying to understand what this means. 
What does the ":=" operator mean ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Unique is a "named argument" and the `:=` is used to assign its value.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/16450/optional-arguments#t=201610050655003223225